# How do I catch a pyqt closeEvent and minimize the dialog instead of exiting?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qdialog

I have a QDialog object.  When the user clicks on the `X` button or presses `Ctrl+Q`, I want the dialog to go to a minimized view or system tray icon, instead of closing.  How do I do that?

Comment: You just have to reimplement the `closeEvent(event)` method in a subclass and minimize the dialog instead of accepting that event.
Or do you mean something different?

Comment: OK, but can you show me some code example? I tried to do something like this, but my program still going to close!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A simple subclass that minimizes instead of closing is the following:

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    # ...
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        # when you want to destroy the dialog set this to True
        self._want_to_close = False

    def closeEvent(self, evnt):
        if self._want_to_close:
            super(MyDialog, self).closeEvent(evnt)
        else:
            evnt.ignore()
            self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized)
```

You can test it with this snippet in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> win = MyDialog()
>>> win.show()
>>> app.exec_()   #after this try to close the dialog, it wont close bu minimize
```

Comment: Thank you to help me. I found my answer. I don't know why `Qt.WindowMinimized` didn't work for me. I used `self.setVisible(False)` instead of that. Also because I used QDialog, in some window managers, user is capable to close dialog with `Esc key`. then I re implement `done` function and make them same.

Comment: In the documentation they say that the way in which the window state is handled is different on the OSes. On some OS the change isn't instantaneous etc. I tried this solution and worked fine on linux.

Comment: This closes the main window, how do you prevent it from closing the main application?