# QDialog - Prevent Closing in Python and PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a login screen dialog written using pyqt and python and it shows a dialog pup up when it runs and you can type in a certin username and password to unlock it basicly. It's just something simple I made in learning pyqt. I'm trying to take and use it somewhere else but need to know if there is a way to prevent someone from using the x button and closing it i would like to also have it stay on top of all windows so it cant be moved out of the way? Is this possible? I did some research and couldn't find anything that could help me.

**Edit:**

as requested here is the code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Test(QtGui.QDialog):
     def __init__(self):
            QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
            self.textUsername = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            self.textPassword = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            self.loginbuton = QtGui.QPushButton('Test Login', self)
            self.loginbuton.clicked.connect(self.Login)
            layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
            layout.addWidget(self.textUsername)
            layout.addWidget(self.textPassword)
            layout.addWidget(self.loginbuton)

    def Login(self):
           if (self.textUsername.text() == 'Test' and
               self.textPassword.text() == 'Password'):
               self.accept()
           else:
                 QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(
                 self, 'Wrong', 'Incorrect user or password')

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if Test().exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: let me get it off my pi one second

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bad news first, it is *not possible* to remove the close button from the window, based on the [Riverbank mailing system](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2008-September/020479.html)

> You can't remove/disable close button because its handled by the
>   window manager, Qt can't do anything there.

Good news, you can override and ignore, so that when the user sends the event, you can ignore or put a message or something.

[Read this article for ignoring the `QCloseEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcloseevent.html)

Also, take a look at this question, [How do I catch a pyqt closeEvent and minimize the dialog instead of exiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365202/how-to-catch-pyqt-closeevent-and-minimize-the-dialog-to-system-try-when-it-calle)

Which uses this:

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    # ...
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        # when you want to destroy the dialog set this to True
        self._want_to_close = False

    def closeEvent(self, evnt):
        if self._want_to_close:
            super(MyDialog, self).closeEvent(evnt)
        else:
            evnt.ignore()
            self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized)
```

Comment: ok thanks but i have one more question if you could update your code on how to keep a user from click out of the box so it would show up as on top and you couldnt click out of it?

Comment: @raspberry.pi I do not have any more time to write the code, but you can achieve what you want by taking a look at `pyqt windows flags`

Comment: now im runnig into a problem a button is overiding another button i think im ussing layout.add.Widget(self.closebutton)

Comment: i mean programmatically

Comment: You **can disable** them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65125495/7426109

Answer (score 7):

You **can** disable the window buttons in PyQt5.

The key is to combine it with "CustomizeWindowHint",
and **exclude the ones you want to be disabled**.

**Example:**

```
#exclude "QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint" or any other window button

self.setWindowFlags(
    QtCore.Qt.Window |
    QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint |
    QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint |
    QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
    )
```

**Result with `QDialog`:**
[image]

**Reference:** https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum

**Tip:** if you want to change flags of the current window, use `window.show()`
after `window.setWindowFlags`,
because it needs to refresh it, so it calls `window.hide()`.

**Tested with `QtWidgets.QDialog` on:**
Windows 10 x32,
Python 3.7.9,
PyQt5 5.15.1
.

Comment: The part about "exclude the ones you want to be disabled" was the key for me.

Comment: nice! For `PyQt6`, use `QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowMinimizeButtonHint`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you want to do this but you can also make your window frameless. To make window frameless you can set the window flag equal to **QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint**